# How can I prove that a function is surjective?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I understood by scrolling through the old posts, that if i have a function like this: $f: \mathbb{R}-\lbrace2\rbrace \rightarrow \mathbb{R} - \lbrace5\rbrace \mid f(x) = \frac{5x + 1}{x - 2}$ i can easily prove this one by explicating for x and looking at the domain ([How can I prove that this function is surjective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2747619/how-can-i-prove-that-this-function-is-surjective)). But if it is given to me something like this:$f: \mathbb{N \times N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \mid f((n,m)) = 2^{n-1}(2m-1)$, how can i prove that is surjective? The fact that i have 2 variable is confusing me.
Thanks, I hope the question is well asked.

UPDATE:
[Proving that $f$ is a bijection from $N$x$N$ to $N$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757313/proving-that-f-is-a-bijection-from-nxn-to-n)

Comment: If you factor out the highest power of $2$ in a given positive integer what remains is an odd interger.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy so if I understand correctly, i consider $(2m-1)$ as an odd integer so now i have $2^{n-1}$, but this function is not surjective. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes! This explains a lot about Kavi comment, but I think the answer given to this post is even clearer,and and it helped me a lot! I will update the question, with this link being very useful anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the definition of surjectivity. A function $f : X \to Y$ is said to be *surjective* iff for each $y \in Y$ there exists $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$. So, if you want to prove a function $f : X \to Y$ is surjective, your proof looks like the following.

Let $y \in Y$ be given. Take $x = \ldots \in X$. Then $f(x) = \cdots = y$. Therefore, $f$ is surjective.

A function with more than one variable can be understood as a function on the Cartesian product of sets. Actually, the set $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is the set of all pairs $(m,n)$ of natural numbers. Therefore, your proof looks like the following.

Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ be given. Take $(m,n) = \ldots \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$. Then $f((m,n)) = \cdots = k$. Therefore, $f$ is surjective.

Here, the part "Take $(m,n) = \ldots \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$." can be replaced by "Take $m = \ldots \in \mathbb{N}$, and take $n = \ldots \in \mathbb{N}$.", because a pair is determined by its components.

Comment: Wow, really useful thanks!